# Rails 3 - using set_primary_key causes routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was searching google and stackoverflow for long time, but I can't find the solution of my problem.

Lately, I was using set_primary_key for a table called "employee", because I need to use ther personnel number as my primary key. If I set the code

```
`set_primary_key :personel_number`
```

(Personel_number is already a collumn which I want to use as primary key) into my model before I do rake db:migrate and do migrating at last, I come into troubles when I try to fill my database via browser:

```
`Couldn't find employee with ID=1`

`app/controllers/mitarbeiters_controller.rb:16:in `show'`
```

Rails searches for employee with ID=1 but it can't find, because I set primary key from personel_number with 601 (e.g.).

Can I do something against it or shall I let Rails create it's own :id first?

Comment: please post the routes to help you

Comment: Yeah rails really doesn't want you to use anything other than auto-incrememented ints for your id. you should just create another field in the model for personnel number, and find/search by that

Comment: ok, I try to be more exact: 
-> set pk in model
-> rake db:migrate
-> rails s and viewing localhost:3000/employees
-> now I type a new employee with personel number (which will be my pk, e.g. 601 ) and name 
-> browser wants to route to employees/1 (http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/z5issu4s/1.PNG), but rails doesn't set any employee with id=1 
-> on SQLite Database browser, I can see something weird: http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/ga0pnpbn/2.png

it seems like trying to set own primary key and eleminating the rails set id causes lots of problems....

Comment: Post your view for 'new' page, and your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like when the page goes to the controller to create the employee you have a redirect to show the new employee and it is using the default id.

Comment: @ Craig: Yeah, I think that is what's happening, but actually, I'm such a rails-beginner that I have no idea how to solve this problem. 

the view for 'new' page: 
`<h1>New mitarbeiter</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', mitarbeiters_path %>`

Comment: I think it's better to watch it on textfile:
>>>>> my view for 'new': http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6663083/new.html.erb.txt
>>>>> my view for _form.html.erb: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6663083/_form.html.erb.txt
>>>> my controller: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6663083/mitarbeiters_controller.txt

note: because I'm not native English speaker, the tables are not in English. "mitarbeiter" = "employee" ; "personalnr" = "personel_number" 

Thanks in advance! :)